# Programmatically Add a Border to a StackPanel in Windows 8

Tags: c#, wpf, code-behind

I'm trying to set the following properties in the C# code behind of StackPanel that I need to add programmatically:

```
BorderThickness
BorderBrush
```

Any idea on how to set these programmatically?

Answer (score 26):

I know this is a year later, but I have found an answer in case someone still needs it.

[Here is a complete example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms743314%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

```
// Create a StackPanel and Add children
StackPanel myStackPanel = new StackPanel();
Border myBorder1 = new Border();
myBorder1.Background = Brushes.SkyBlue;
myBorder1.BorderBrush = Brushes.Black;
myBorder1.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1);
TextBlock txt1 = new TextBlock();
txt1.Foreground = Brushes.Black;
txt1.FontSize = 12;
txt1.Text = "Stacked Item #1";
myBorder1.Child = txt1;

Border myBorder2 = new Border();
myBorder2.Background = Brushes.CadetBlue;
myBorder2.Width = 400;
myBorder2.BorderBrush = Brushes.Black;
myBorder2.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1);
TextBlock txt2 = new TextBlock();
txt2.Foreground = Brushes.Black;
txt2.FontSize = 14;
txt2.Text = "Stacked Item #2";
myBorder2.Child = txt2;

// Add the Borders to the StackPanel Children Collection
myStackPanel.Children.Add(myBorder1);
myStackPanel.Children.Add(myBorder2);
mainWindow.Content = myStackPanel;
```

Answer (score 1):

The StackPanel does not have a BorderThickness or BorderBrush properties.  Only Background.  If you want to set those, you would need to wrap the StackPanel in a Border control:

```
<Border  x:Name="StackBorder">
<StackPanel>
</Border>
```

You can then call:

```
StackBorder.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1);
StackBorder.BorderBrush = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Red);
```

Comment: Great idea...the only issue is that I'll have "x" number of StackPanels so I need to create all of them in the code behind.  I'm able to programmatically create the Border and StackPanel objects, I just can't seem to find the correct syntax to add the StackPanel to the Border.  Any ideas?

Comment: @iTrout It sounds like you should be using an Itemscontrol rather than creating things in code.

Comment: @mydogisbox - I'm using a Callisto Flyout so I need to build it in code.  If I could load the Callisto Flyout with XAML, that would be a dream come true!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set border properties on the [StackPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.stackpanel.aspx) object itself. You place the StackPanel object inside a [Border](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.border.aspx) object and set the `BorderThickness` and `BorderBrush` properties on the Border object with something like:

```
myBorder.BorderBrush = Brushes.Black;
myBorder.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1);
```